# Ubuntu mysql stops working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am have vps setup with ubuntu 14 server. I have lamp stack installed. Everything works perfect but mysql server stops frequently and i have to restart it manually.  Here is my my.cnf mysql config file.

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
    #
    # You can copy this to one of:
    # - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
    # - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
    # 
    # One can use all long options that the program supports.
    # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
    # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
    #
    # For explanations see
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

And following is my mysqltuner output.

```
-------- General Statistics ------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 38K (Tables: 34)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 11M (Tables: 101)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 101

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1h 13m 27s (2K q [0.464 qps], 130 conn, TX: 5M, RX: 332K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 81% / 19%
[--] Total buffers: 192.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 597.8M (121% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (12/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/196.0K
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 33.9% (493 cached / 1K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 77 sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 33% (166 on disk / 498 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 90% (12 created / 130 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 94% (178 open / 189 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 11% (116/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 11.9M/128.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
    General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
```

And here is my memory uses

```
Every 5.0s: free -m                                                         Sun Jul  3 03:12:12 2016

         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:           490        476         13         64         10        183
-/+ buffers/cache:        281        208
Swap:            0          0          0

What can be wrong here. Is there some misconfig on my my.cnf or something else is killing mysql. Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: Can you please post output of `tail /var/log/mysql/error.log` ?

Comment: There is nothing on error.log file. Its empty

Answer (score 2):

Its possible that mysql runs out of memory. It happens when your system lacks swapping ( i.e. When memory gets exhausted, programs can't be transferred from main memory to a "swap" file in order to prevent system from memory failures ).

Swap explanation from [Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space):

> Linux divides its physical RAM (random access memory) into chucks of
>   memory called pages. Swapping is the process whereby a page of memory
>   is copied to the preconfigured space on the hard disk, called swap
>   space, to free up that page of memory. The combined sizes of the
>   physical memory and the swap space is the amount of virtual memory
>   available.

You can tweak "innodb_buffer_pool_size" to reduce indexing and caching footprints in the memory.

> Ideally, you set the size of the buffer pool to as large a value as
>   practical, leaving enough memory for other processes on the server to
>   run without excessive paging. The larger the buffer pool, the more
>   InnoDB acts like an in-memory database, reading data from disk once
>   and then accessing the data from memory during subsequent reads.
>   Buffer pool size is configured using the innodb_buffer_pool_size
>   configuration option.

According to [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html):

Solution:

1. Add this under [mysqld] : `innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M`

then make a swap file:

1. dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=100M count=40
2. mkswap /swapfile
3. swapon /swapfile

and add this to `/etc/fstab`:

`/swapfile      none    swap    sw      0       0`

Comment: should i add this line on my.cnf innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M? And can you explain about the swapfile please. What this will do? It will help other users also who are having similar issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes you should add it to `my.cnf` file. Sure, I will edit the post with additional explanations. Hope it solves your problem.